# FusionAuth email subject not supporting special language characters

Tags: utf-8, fusionauth

Is there any way to pass special language characters such as 'ąęćń' in the subject of an email template in fusionauth ?

Comment: This should work already. Can you provide additional details such as operating system version, browser version, database type and version?

Comment: The problem was on all systems. After some time of search bellow there is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to encode the string `subject` as MIME header using `javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility`

```
MimeUtility.encodeText(subject, "utf-8", "B")
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll do some additional testing with this code to see if I can replicate and then resolve the issue.

Comment: The `MimeMessage.setSubject` does use `MimeUtility.encodeText` - but it we were using `Message.setSubject` which passes `null` as the character set so if the operating system was using `UTF-8` it would work, or if the OS was set to something else - or if it defaulted to `ISO-8859_1` the subject would be rendered as `???` upon delivery. This will be corrected, thanks!

Comment: Bug will be fixed under this issue. https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/231

Comment: Great !
Same problem occured when I was adding the email template content as html.
Without calling `new String(html, encoding)` where encoding was explicitly `UTF-8` fusionauth was not reading the characters properly. This seems a normal behavior however I suggest to add this information somewhere in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Lechu67 we'll do a few other checks to make sure we've got all of this fixed up for the next release. Thanks for the assist!